# C++ templates and runtime

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a template factory class such that given an int i, it will create an instance of the i'th class in its parameter list; and i has to be a runtime variable.  The idea starts as follows: Let's say we have types A, B. We can create the class below easily:

```cpp
class factory{
  void* create(size_t i) {
    return (i==0) new A() : (i==1 ? new B() :nullptr);  
  }
};
```

We have to use `void*` as return type but this works.  Now how can we expand it with templates such that we can do:

```cpp
auto f = factory<A,B,C,D,E,F>();
A* a = f.create(0);
E* e = f.create(4);
```

I've already spent a solid 10 hours on this and came up with a solution that works if i is known at compile time.  Here it is:

```cpp
template <size_t i, class first, class... rest>
struct choose: public choose<i - 1, rest...> {};

template <class first, class... rest>
struct choose<0, first, rest...> {
    using type = first;
};

template<class... cls>
class factory {
public:
    template <size_t j, typename... ArgTypes>
    inline typename choose<j, cls...>::type* create(ArgTypes... args) {
        using f = typename choose<j, cls...>::type;
        return new f(args...);
    }
};
```

The problem is that variable j needs to be known at compile time, which is not something I want.
I also don't want to create the objects, put them into an array and then just get it from the array. I understand that would make my pain go away, but the purpose of this exercise is to learn templates.

---

The Context of this code is for a simple web framework I am making using c++.  I want to have Controller classes and an Application class:

```cpp
class Controller {
   virtual get(params) =0;
   virtual post(params) =0;
};
class ControllerA: Controller {
public:
   constexpr static char route[] = "/home";  //this controller handles this route
   // virtual implementation
};
class ControllerB: Controller {
public:
   constexpr static char route[] = "/user";
   // virtual implementation
};

template<class... controllers>
class Application {
  factory<controllers...> f; 
public:
  Application() {
    //create router and give it all of the routes from the controllers in the template.
  }
  dispatchPostRequest(request) {
    int i = doRounting(request.route); //router returns a number that specifies the 
    //index of controller in the template parameter pack. 
    f.create(i) -> post()
  }
};
```

To me this seems like a simple concept. Java/JS/Python implementation would have taken me 20 minutes each.  I do not understand why I'm having such a tough time with it in C++.

Comment: C++ template parameters are compile-time constructs, if you need to vary based on runtime information then a factory template is likely simply the wrong solution. What exactly do you think a template would gain you over a switch-case for example?

Comment: Two things: 1) this makes user code a lot easier since they can just create an Application object and pass the Controllers as template parameter 2) I want to go from the router determination to creation of Controller in constant time (not linear in number of controllers).  There must be a way to do this.

Comment: The fundamental sticking point for me is that what I'm trying to do is fundamentally a compile time operation.  I could just write a big router function that tests for equality of route strings and then directly calls hard coded controller methods.   Meta programming is supposed to replace hard coding but be just as fast as hard coding.  So I'm trying to get there.

Comment: That can be done if all classes `A, B, C, D, E` derive from the same base class. Othewrwise, how would you specify the type that the `create` function returns (this info is needed in compile time)?

Comment: Sure.  In my (last) example every template type parameter extends Controller.   It doesn't matter that much anyways.  I'm ok with void*.

Comment: May be ````std::tuple_element```` can help you? Please see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element

Comment: Nice. I did not know about tuple_element.  It doesn't solve this problem but it does what my template code did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also don't want to create the objects, put them into an array [...]

That can be the basis for a possible solution; though you won't add *objects* into that array, but *creator functions*.

However already your very simple piece of code showed up a memory leak:

```
f.create(i) -> post();
```

When gets the object deleted again??? So make the creator functions safe by returning a smart pointer!

Going via `void*` is never safe either (apart from preventing smart pointers – you cannot `delete` void pointers!), you can just far too easily apply a bad cast then:

```
std::string* s = static_cast<std::string*>(create<std::string, std::complex<double>, std::vector<int>>(1));
```

See the problem? But with your `Controller` base class, you *have* already all the necessary infrastructure you need to keep that factory function (or class) safe! So a possible solution might look like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<Controller> makeT()
{
    return std::make_unique<T>();
}

template <typename ... Types>
std::unique_ptr<Controller> create(size_t index)
{
    static std::unique_ptr<Controller>(*creators[])() =
#if 0
    { &std::make_unique<Types> ... };
#else
    { &makeT<Types>... };
#endif
    return creators[index]();
}
```

Unfortunately, we cannot use `std::make_unique` directly, as each instantiation has a different return type (of unique_ptr of the specific class!), thus we get incompatible pointers. So we need that intermediate function...

Due to smart pointer (avoiding the necessity for explicit deletion) and polymorphism (avoiding the need for correct cast), the call above now is safe.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the bits about leaking and void* casting.  I was just presenting code that is relevant to the point of question and I didn't think memory was.  This solution seems to work, though I didn't get the #if 0 line.

Comment: I also came up with this one liner: 

template <class... cls> Controller* (*arr[sizeof...(cls)])() = {[]{return dynamic_cast<Controller*>(new cls);}...};

Comment: @TahaPourjalali It would have been nice to be able to use std::make_unique directly from within the template function. I left that piece of code there for demonstration, but deactivated it with `#if 0`...

Comment: I see what you mean.  You could use unique_ptr constructor  with Controller type and give it new ChildType.  Then your pointers would have been the same type.

Comment: @TahaPourjalali GCC doesn't accept that one-liner – neither inside (*'a template declaration cannot appear at block scope'*) nor outside the function (*'parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’'* and *'expansion pattern ‘<lambda>’ contains no argument packs'*); not sure if the latter is only due to GCC's specific lambda implementation or correct according to standard.

Comment: I think I had a typo. I posted it as an answer and that one compiled and ran on clang.

Comment: But you still need to pack constructing a child type and assigning to parent unique_ptr into some function. I experimented with lambda before, too, but that got far more complex than a simple separate template function. Assigning a unique_ptr of child type to unique_ptr of parent type is fine, so I used std::make_unique in that helper function, too – for convenience, actually...

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the function with `<typename HEAD, typename... TAIL>`. This may be a private function that is used as an utility:

```
template<class... cls>
class factory {
private:
    template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
    void* create_impl(size_t i) {
        if (i == 0)
            return new Head;
        else
            return create_impl<Tail...>(i - 1);
    }
public:
    void* create(size_t i) {
        return create_impl<cls...>(i);
    }
};
```

So you have a runtime parameter `i` plus compile time template arguments `Head` and 'Tail'. `Tail` is a variadic. Whenever the runtime parameter is 0, you retuen `Head`. Otherwise you employ recursion.

I'm using `void*` for simplicity, you may have a more complicated hierarchy.

**Upd.**
Ok, another approach on top of the first one. You may implement a function that should be called once, and that would create a table of other functions that should be called based on the index.

```
template<class... cls>
class factory {
private:
    template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
    void* create_impl(size_t i) {
        if (i == 0)
            return new Head;
        else
            return create_impl<Tail...>(i - 1);
    }

    function<void*()> make_func(size_t i) {
        return make_func_impl(i);
    }

    template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
    function<void*()> make_func_impl(size_t i) {
        if (i == 0)
            return create<Head>;
        else
            return make_func_impl<Tail...>(i - 1);
    }

    template <typename Class>
    Class* create() {
        return new Class;
    }

    vector<function<void*()>> m_table;
public:
    factory() {
        m_table.reserve(sizeof...(cls));
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof...(cls); ++i) {
            m_table[i] = make_func(i);
        }
    }

    void* create(size_t i) {
        return m_table[i]();
    }
};
```

This still may require linear recursion, but this will be performed once. You may use `m_table` as a precomputed table of functions based on runtime index.

Comment: Nice! this solves most of the problems but is recursive.  I think it can be improved to be constant time though (i.e. not recursive).

Comment: @TahaPourjalali, actually that IS constant time because the recursion will be unrolled and optimized in compile time.

Comment: The if statements will be there. I don't see how the compiler can get rid of those.  If i = 100, we'll have 100 if checks.   And the way I was thinking of avoiding it doesn't work either.  I wonder if I can get a compile time array of template functions or lambdas that call the constructors.  Then the index of array can be referred to at runtime while lambdas themselves are created at compile time.

Comment: @TahaPourjalali Ok, you still can improve the solution making the function `constexpr`. In this case if compiler knows the index value, it may optimize the code. If compiler does not know the value, you have to deal with that in runtime. Making the function `inline` may help, but doesn't guarantee anything. If you know the number of types a priori, you may try to use `switch`, but better reconsider the design.

Comment: Neither g++ nor clang++ seems to be able to compile that: https://godbolt.org/z/XxPioK

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this two liner too:

```cpp
template <class... cls>
Controller* (*creator_array[sizeof...(cls)])() = {[]{return dynamic_cast<Controller*>(new cls());}...};
```

It creates an array of creator functions, similar to the answer above. So you can do:

```cpp
Controller* (*arr[2])() = creator_array<ControllerA, ControllerB>;
arr[0]() //creates new ControllerA
arr[1]() //create new ControllerB
```